# How to consume service api with applicationKey in Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

I am new to Windows app development. I am trying to consume service api with mobile service client with following block of code

```
 MobileServiceClient mSClient;
 mSClient = new MobileServiceClient("https://*******.azure-mobile.net/", "UFakeKkrayuAeVnosdfghrwvnhdfVAcjYziYFSFHUV89");

 Dictionary<string, string> userobj = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 userobj.Add("UserName", "username");
 userobj.Add("Password", "password");
 userobj.Add("DeviceUID", "010092780200134E0300215F0400CC37050083D807006B9B080066010900267F");
 userobj.Add("DeviceToken", "device_123");
 userobj.Add("OSVersion", "WindowsPhone");
 userobj.Add("AppVersion", "2.0");
 userobj.Add("DeviceModel", "Windows phone");
 userobj.Add("DeviceTypeID", "1");
 userobj.Add("DeviceAlertsOn","true");      

 var responce = mSClient.InvokeApiAsync("user/loguserin", HttpMethod.Post, userobj);
```

But I am not getting proper response:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,
Srinivas.

Comment: you need to use await when calling an async method

Comment: to add to jason and sushi, when you don't use await, your responce will contain the task object. You can access the status and errors from your `responce` object. You can then later do `await responce` to run it. This is helpful for more debugging

Comment: Thanks Neville, Can you please give me some proper block of code to get responce

Comment: the way you have written it is fine. You can inspect the object in debug mode. And just have the line `await responce` below that line. I do this often to test async functions

Answer (score 1):

You are not *awaiting* the async method and thus you are seeing the status of `WaitingForActivition`:

```
var responce= await mSClient.InvokeApiAsync(.......
```

Comment: Thank you Sushi for your reply, i tried with your answer now i am getting following exception      An exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: @srinivaschalla You need to look at the `Value` and `Response` properies of the exception (`MobileServiceInvalidO‌​perationException`) to determine why the server is rejecting your call. `Provides additional details of an invalid operation specific to a Mobile Service.
`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.mobileserviceinvalidoperationexception?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Getting respoce as   {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=05b093af5f4e7c6d198da2b2771de80c714f0499531fcab7ac6cc84e48dfeafc;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=chiefservices.azure-mobile.net
  Date: Wed, 27 Sep 2017 05:08:30 GMT
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 81
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}}   and Value as null

Comment: @srinivaschalla In your code, you are sending the strings "username" and "password" instead the values of those variables, but otherwise you would need to post another question with the details of the failure and details what `user/loguserin` expects on the server side.